# Add a SharePoint group to a role using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, groups, roles

I'm writing a script that adds user to a group (for example readers) on a site using a form and a PeoplePicker field. But I also want the script to be able to handle not only users, but also if it is a SP-group.

This is what I have so far:

```
var addUsersToRole = function (clientContext, web, roleType, userNameArray) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    var roleAssignments = web.get_roleAssignments();
    var roleDefinitions = web.get_roleDefinitions();
    var binding = SP.RoleDefinitionBindingCollection.newObject(clientContext);
    var role = roleDefinitions.getByType(roleType);
    binding.add(role);
    $.each(userNameArray, function (index, userName) {
        var user = web.ensureUser(userName);
        roleAssignments.add(user, binding);
    });

    var onSuccess = function (data) {
        deferred.resolve();
    };
    var onFailure = function (data) {
        deferred.reject("Could not add users to role");
    };

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFailure);
    return deferred;
};
```

Now I'm using `var user = web.ensureUser(userName);` to get my user, but this doesn't work if the it's not a user, but rather a group. I could easily get weather the item is in fact a user or a group, but I don't know how to add it to the role. I need something like `web.ensureGroup(groupName)`.

Edit: I'm talking about SharePoint-group, not AD-groups

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine also for AD groups. Did you mean AD group or SharePoint group?

Comment: FYI (And I'm not sure if this relates to your case) you cannot add Sharepoing groups to other SharePoint groups.  Only users or Active Directory groups can be added to SharePoint groups.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough, I meant SharePointgroup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried just getting the Group object and passing that in the roleAssignments.Add call in place of the user object?  Something like this:

```
var memberGroup = web.get_siteGroups().getByName("Members");
roleAssignments.add(memberGrooup, binding);
```

I know I've done this but don't recall exactly how.